# How to get data from substring of perticular column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a column in which Data is already inserted. Format of data is like "Item(Free)","My Item(Priced)". Now according to the "Free" and "Priced" i need to get the data. Is there any solution to get data according to Sub string?

Comment: What do you mean by "get" - do you want to sum, filter or something else? For a sum use SUMIF with wildcards

Answer (score 1):

To check cell `A1` try this:

`=IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Free",""))=LEN(A1),"Do what you need when Priced","Do what you need when Free")`

This assumes that whenever in a cell you check there is no "Free" there will be "Priced". It is easy to make it more generic, but it makes it a little cluttered - let us know if that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To find substring in cell .. you may use SEARCH

The formula is

```
= SEARCH("FREE", upper(A1))
```

So if A1 contain `"Item(Free)"` .. the result is `6`